# Is there a proper term for a physical path accessed through a symbolic link?

Tags: symlink, filenames

I've spent the last hour deliberating on what to name a property which means the total opposite of *"resolved, physical realpath"*.

For example, let's assume `/foo/bar/` is an ordinary physical path. If a symlink was created at `/quux` which simply pointed to `/foo`, is it appropriate to refer to everything accessed via `/quux/foo/bar/` as a "symlinked path"...?

This is mostly a question about nomenclature, because I'm uncertain if there's a more accurate way of referring to an unresolved pathname. I'd use "working path", but the term sounds too process-specific.

If context is needed, it's for a filesystem API where a routine determines if an extra system-call should be made for a resource whose path isn't entirely physical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be really pedantic, you may say that there is not *really* such a thing as a "physical path".  Unix has

- Absolute Pathname: A pathname beginning with a single or more than two `<slash>` characters.
- Relative Pathname: A pathname not beginning with a `<slash>` character.

If a pathname contains a symbolic link, it is still a "pathname". There is no other terms for it in the POSIX standard.

However, the `pwd` utility has two flags, `-P` and `-L`, but with no indication as to what these letters abbreviate:

> `-L`
>
> If the `PWD` environment variable contains an absolute pathname of the current directory and the pathname does not contain any components that are dot or dot-dot, `pwd` shall write this pathname to standard output, except that if the `PWD` environment variable is longer than `{PATH_MAX}` bytes including the terminating null, it is unspecified whether pwd writes this pathname to standard output or behaves as if the `-P` option had been specified. Otherwise, the `-L` option shall behave as the `-P` option.
>
> `-P`
>
> The pathname written to standard output shall not contain any components that refer to files of type symbolic link. If there are multiple pathnames that the `pwd` utility could write to standard output, one beginning with a single `<slash>` character and one or more beginning with two `<slash>` characters, then it shall write the pathname beginning with a single `<slash>` character. The pathname shall not contain any unnecessary `<slash>` characters after the leading one or two `<slash>` characters.

Of course, it's possible to infer the meaning of *logical* and *physical* to these two flags, and the GNU coreutils version of this utility even has these two words as long options.

So the answer is "logical path".

Answer (score 1):

Well a couple of these are more colloquiel than definite, but:

If the link will always point to the file irregardless of whether or not either the orginal file or the link is moved `Alias` should be used (note that an alias can be used to read files and directories, but not write to the original).

If the link can be moved but the file cannot, and data can be read from a linked file/directory through the link, but not written then `Soft Link`, `Symlink`, or `Shortcut` should be used.

If both the link and target can be moved, and data can be both read from and written to the file/directory through the link, then `Hard Link` should be used.

For example a `Symlink/Soft Link` would be read by the system as `/foo/bar/` when the link was accessed. An `Alias` would access it as `/quux/foo/bar/` when reading, but `/foo/bar/` when writing, and a `Hard Link` would access it as `/quux/foo/bar/` when writing as well as reading.